# Python equivalent of Java's AtomicReferenceArray

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm modifying a python codebase. and I'm wondering if python 3.9 has the equivalent of Java's `AtomicReferenceArray`?
There's a brief mention of this in https://peps.python.org/pep-0583/, but it seems that it's been withdrawn?

EDIT:
Use case : imagine object A with 10 fields. main thread will populate the array with say 100 of object A with only field 1 & 8 populated. then, Thread T1 will iterate through the array and populate only fields 2 and 5, and T2 will only populate field 3 and 4, T3 field 6 and 7, and so on.

Thanks

Comment: In general, this is not a problem in Python because of the GIL.  Why don't you describe your use case?

Comment: @TimRoberts so,main thread will populate the array with say 100 of object A. each of object A will have 10 fields. Thread T1 will iterate through the array and populate only fields 1,2 and 5, and T2 will only populate field 3 and 4, T3 field 6 and 7, and so on.

Comment: @TimRoberts I just updated the question with the use case

Comment: @medaliama: If any given slot in the array is only accessed by a single thread, this will work fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts: The GIL's documented guarantees (swapped only between opcodes, or when manually released by a C extension) wouldn't be enough if individual slots were being mutated in multiple threads (the current implementation of the GIL would protect simple `x[i] += 1` operations as long as no function calls or loops were embedded in the statement, but that's not a guarantee, and it has changed within the Python 3.x timeframe).

Comment: @ShadowRanger in my case, each object in the array will be mutated by multiple threads. however, only one thread will mutate each field in each object. so, does this mean GIL doesn't protect this?

Comment: @medaliama: If the array is prepopulated with all the objects (you're not *replacing* the objects with new objects), *then* the threads the set the fields of each object are launched, the GIL should protect you. You'd have no read-modify-write issues, and the GIL protects simple assignments like that just fine.

Comment: I see. Thanks all for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need that while one thread is updating the instances in each position, no other thread uses a partially set version of the item at that position, right?

This can be built in Python, inheriting from `collections.abc.MutableSequence`,(https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) adding some internal state
as to which elements are locked at a given time, and, if needed, restrict element retrieving at the `__getitem__` method.

I won't of course, write all methods in the Java spec - but this should get you the grasp, should you need any other methods:

```
import threading
from collections.abc import MutableSequence, Mapping
from typing import Any


class AtomicList(MutableSequence):
    timeout = 5

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.data = list(*args)
        self.locks = {}
        self.lock = threading.RLock()
        self.local = threading.local()
        self.local.current_item = None
        self.local.locked = False

    def __call__(self, index:int):
        if getattr(self.local, "current_item", None) is not None:
            raise RuntimeError("Current thread already modifying item at position {self.local.current_item}")
        self.local.current_item = index
        return self

    def __enter__(self):
        with self.lock:
            if getattr(self.local, "current_item", None) is not None:
                raise RuntimeError("Call the instance with the desired index in order to lock it")
            self.locks[self.local.current_item] = threading.current_thread(), threading.Event()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        with self.lock:
            self.locks[self.local.current_item][1].set()
            del self.locks[self.local.current_item]
            self.local.current_item = None

    def _unlock(self):
        self.local.current_item = None

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        with self.lock:
            if not index in self.locks or self.locks[index][0] is threading.current_thread():
                return self.data[index]
            if self.locks[index][1].wait(self.timeout):
                return self.data[index]
            raise RuntimeError(f"Timed out on locked item at position {index}")

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        with self.lock:
            if not index in self:
                self.data[index] = value
                return
            if index in self.locks:
                if self.locks[index][0] is threading.current_thread():
                    self.data[index] = value
                    return
                if self.locks[index][1].wait(self.timeout):
                    # warning: list member changed just after update.
                    self.data[index] = value
                    return
            raise RuntimeError(f"Timed out on locked item at position {index}")

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        with self.lock:
            if index in self.locks:
                raise RuntimeError(f"trying to remove item locked for modification at {index}")
            del self.data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return len(self.data)

    def insert(self, index, value):
        with self.lock:
            self.data.insert(index, value)
            
    def update_item(self, index, attrs: Mapping[str, Any]):
        """Create similar methods from the Java Atomic Reference Array as desired
        """
        with self(index):
            element = self[index]
            for key, value in attrs:
                setattr(element, key, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.data!r})"
```

This should work (an example of how is in the `update_item` method)- but if some other thread extracts an element and works in it "out of the list", it is not atomically locked, as the elements, once retrieved, are normal Python objects.

Of course, I created the `__enter__` and `__exit__`  methods so that it "feels pythonic" - one can just implement the verbose methods as is the Java way, and skip those.

If that is desired, another layer of indirection is needed, in which list elements are only retrieved as wrapped proxy objects that can't be changed, and all modifications have to be made through atomic_list methods.